# Event attached to button JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, button

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-9"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            <div class="login-form">
                <form role="form" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nick">Nick:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nick-log" />
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Hasło</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password-log" id="password" />
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-default">Pamiętaj mnie</label>
                    </div>
                    <button id="login-button" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Zaloguj się</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
```

JS Code:

```
    $(function() {
        var checkLogForm=function(){
            alert('anything');
        };

        $('#login-button').on("click", fn)
    });
```

I don't know why but I can't attach any event to element #login-button. It works even with other elements in form. I've tried also with bind() function but it still doesn't work.
Please help!

Comment: What is fn? and missing a `;` at the end of that line.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$('#login-button').on("click", checkLogForm)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your html

```
<button id="login-button" class="btn btn-success">Zaloguj się</button>
```

instead of

```
<button id="login-button" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Zaloguj się</button>
```

and change your js

```
$(document).on('click', '#login-button', function() {
     alert('anything');
});
```

I'm not sure but i think it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
   always  Use **ON()** instead of **click()**
```

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/ncsr4tgh/1/) Check this **https://jsfiddle.net/ncsr4tgh/1/**  its working.....

Answer (score 0):

ChecklogForm or any other function needs to be either outaide of document ready function or both ChecklogForm and binding code need to be inside the same document ready function.

Answer (score 0):

in `$('#login-button').on("click", fn)`, `fn` is name of the callback function which will be called when an click event occurs on the button, which in your case is `checkLogForm`.